# CTFrameGetLineOrigins( ) Issue occurred when I translated the project from OC to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-text

### My Situation:

I am trying to translate an open source project, written in Objective-C, to Swift. I have been obstructed by an `CGPoint` Struct issue for several days.

```
CGPoint lineOrigins[numberOfLines];  

// An array includes some CGPoint elements which written in OC.
```

After solved it, I am not sure whether it correct because complier thrown none error.

```
var lineOrigins = [CGPoint](count: numberOfLines, repeatedValue: CGPointZero)

// The Swift Code translated from above OC Code.
```

Another `CTFrameGetLineOrigins()` Issue just showed in my project.

### Part of Objective-C Code:

```
- (void)drawFramesetter:(CTFramesetterRef)framesetter
   attributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attributedString
          textRange:(CFRange)textRange
             inRect:(CGRect)rect
            context:(CGContextRef)c
{
                      .
                      .
                      .
CFArrayRef lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame);
NSInteger numberOfLines = CFArrayGetCount(lines);
CGPoint lineOrigins[numberOfLines];
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, numberOfLines), lineOrigins);
                      .
                      .
                      .
}
```

### Part of Swift Code:

```
func drawFramesetter(framesetter: CTFramesetterRef,
attributedString _attributedString: NSAttributedString,
textRange _textRange: CFRange,
inRect rect: CGRect, context c: CGContextRef) {
                      .
                      .
                      .
var lines: CFArrayRef = CTFrameGetLines(frame)
var numberOfLines: NSInteger = CFArrayGetCount(lines)
var lineOrigins = [CGPoint](count: numberOfLines, repeatedValue: CGPointZero)
CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame, CFRangeMake(0, numberOfLines), lineOrigins)
                      .
                      .
                      .
}
```

### My Problem:

The error, `Cannot invoke 'CTFrameGetLineOrigins' with an argument list of type '(CTFrame, CFRange, [(CGPoint)])'`, showed up.

- After checked the official document, I found that `CTFrameGetLineOrigins` is declared as `CTFrameGetLineOrigins(frame: CTFrame!, range: CFRange, origins: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)` in Swift.
- And it also be declared as `CTFrameGetLineOrigins(CTFrameRef frame, CFRange range, CGPoint origins[])` in Objective-C.
- The difference between two function parameters is `CGPoint`. Come On!!! `CGPoint` Again?

### My Question:

- I guess the error was triggered by the parameter of `CGPoint`. I must make some mistakes when I translated `[CGPoint]` to `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>`. Can anyone tell what's difference between that two types?
- Please tell how to solve this problem.

A big appreciation for your time and guide.

Ethan Joe

Comment: Passing the array as "inout argument" with `CTFrameGetLineOrigins( ..., &origins)` should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Well... It works! Why should I add the `&` mark ?

Comment: Look up "Interacting with C APIs" in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation ...

Comment: OK!!! I'll check that chapter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just found that there already is a very similar question :)